# Java: Changing the direction of a moving object

Tags: java, math, animation, vector

I have a moving object , has it's own initial direction and position.

This is my code below

```
mPosVertices[0] + vecDirection.x * delta
```

From the code above i can make the object move straightline.. what if i want to move the object curve...

I tried changed the direction vector like this:

```
newDirection = new Vector2D(
            (newDirection.x * Math.cos(radian) + newDirection.y * Math.sin(radian)),
            (-1 * newDirection.x * Math.sin(radian) + newDirection.y * Math.cos(radian)));
```

The object doesn't seems to go curvely.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't show us your code of the object we can't help you so much but i think that you can control your object in "X" and "Y" and it would look something like this.

```
mPosVertices[0].velX += vecDirection.x * delta;

mPosVertices[0].velY += vecDirection.y * delta;
```

Comment: vecDirection is a subtraction between center of the screen and the object location in normalized form. Delta is the time stamp. where mPosVertices is the initial position of the object.